# Java EE Session Issue - Different behavior on IE/Chrome & Firefox

Tags: jakarta-ee, session-variables

I'm currently working on a Java EE application (Struts 1.1), deployed on an OracleAS server (pretty old technologies...)

There is an issue with a data that is reloaded from the session on a page.

In short, depending on the browser the behaviour of the session is not the same. I've been trying to debug this on Eclipse + Tomcat and there's the behaviour i'm seeing (assuming there's also the same bug, i'm guessing the behaviour is the same on OracleAS) :

On Firefox I have on the first call

```
session.setAttribute("myobject",myform);
```

The reference indicated when I inspect is :

**com.project.ObjectForm@1a0e2d1[.....]**

On the next page when i'm loading the same object (which was never modified using setAttribute again) :

```
ObjectForm myform = session.getAttribute("myobject");
```

The reference is now

**com.project.ObjectForm@1a0e2d1[.....]**

Values are the same, reference of sub-objects also, everything works fine.

On IE and Chrome, the references change (**com.project.ObjectForm@ad8e84** when I setAttribute(...) and **com.project.ObjectForm@1ee2c5** when I load again on the next page with getAttribute(...), the pages tested being exactly the same than on Firefox with same user data, etc...), worse, some of the data is actually lost! Example one of the string of the ObjectForm goes from *forward=success* to *forward=*, hence the bug!

My first question would be : Is all of this normal? And why oh why would the behaviour of session (server side) would differ depending on the browser, i'm not an expert on sessions, so i'm assuming there's a lack in my knowledge here?

Second one would be : is it actually possible that my data is changed apart from my own setAttribute and getAttribute (since the reference appears to be the same on firefox, if I were to change the object, would it directly be changed in my session?)?

I've checked the browser data passed, jsessionid is good in both case, so it doesn't seem to be coming from here.

Comment: Sessions are backed by cookies. Are cookies enabled or disabled in the mentioned browsers?

Comment: Cookies of course enabled on both browser. Then again i'm assuming if it wasn't the case i wouldn't even be able to get my objects whereas here the whole application is running smoothly except for this particular issue.

Comment: Is Struts or OracleAS doing anything special (intentional or otherwise) based on the user agent?  In addition, are you using `GET` or `POST` to transition between pages?  I'm wondering if a parameter is getting dropped? (especially if the browsers are sending the parameters in a different order)

Comment: There is some part of the code on the user agent, but it's not used in this particular case, the only change would actually be a total redirection of the page to a "mobile" version. Parameters are on POST, and as mentionned, there is no difference on the parameters. Still, when the page is called on the developer tool there is one of the parameters mentionned with : actionTable:(unable to decode value) on Chrome, not really of much concern, but i can click on view URL encoded and it's ok.

Comment: Also, none of those parameters actually has anything to do with the get and set in the session (then again i cannot assure this has not some kind of side effect on the program.